# How to update persisting state of intellij idea plugin in test class?

Tags: java, testing, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm developing plugin for Intellij Idea and doing some tests. In one of my tests I need persisting state to be updated. But it doesn't happens and neither `loadState` nor `getState` is called.

I wrote class that implements `PersistingStateComponent` (i think I did it correctly because it's not the first time I did it). In one test I call method that adds data to State class, and it's successfully added but not saved. Another one should get that data,  but it gets empty `State`. Test class implements  `LightPlatformTestCase.`

Documentation says :

> Persistent Component Lifecycle The loadState() method is called after
>   the component has been created (only if there is some non-default
>   state persisted for the component), and after the XML file with the
>   persisted state is changed externally (for example, if the project
>   file was updated from the version control system). In the latter case,
>   the component is responsible for updating the UI and other related
>   components according to the changed state.
>
> The getState() method is called every time the settings are saved (for
>   example, on frame deactivation or when closing the IDE). If the state
>   returned from getState() is equal to the default state (obtained by
>   creating the state class with a default constructor), nothing is
>   persisted in the XML. Otherwise, the returned state is serialized in
>   XML and stored.

So is it possible that none of these conditions happen?

Can I do something in test method to update my persisting state?

Or it supposed to work and I should look  for issue in my code?

**Update:** When I run plugin it works fine.

My class looks like that:

```
@State(name = "MyStateName", storages = {@Storage(id="MyStateId", file = "D:/MyStateName.xml")})
public class MyClass
  implements PersistentStateComponent<MyClass.State> {

  public static class State{
    Integer someValue  = 10;
  }

  State myState = new State();

  public State getState() {
    return myState;
  }

  public void loadState(State state) {
    myState = state;
  }

  public SFApexClassWrapp getValue() {
    return myState.value;
  }

  public void addValue(Integer value) {
    myState.value = value;
  }

}
```

Comment: Does the persistent state get loaded / saved when you run the plugin itself? Are you using the `implements PersistentStateComponent<Xxx.State>` pattern - can you post some code showing this and the `State` class? (and is it an inner class?)

Comment: It's get saved when I run the plugin itself. I updated my question.

Comment: And please take a look at my second question:
I have some configuration class, and I need to store several instances of it. I tried to create a List of these objects in my State class and it doesn't work. How can I do that? Is it possible to store such objects in different xml-files with different names?

Comment: Well if the plugin works fine but the test fails - then the problem lies with the test ;) How did you pick `LightPlatformTestCase` as being the correct test for this situation?

Comment: I picked `LightPlatformTestCase` because it provides Application and Project which I need to get my project and application services  etc. I'm not sure that's the best test but I didn't find anything better. Actually my experience in testing is very poor, it's nearly doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

When you're using PersistentStateComponent, your only responsibility as a plugin developer is to return an instance of the State class. Therefore, the only thing that it makes sense to test for you as a plugin developer is that your instance is returned correctly. You don't need to test the XML serialization, because it's part of IntelliJ IDEA's code, which is not your responsibility and is already reasonably well-tested.

That's why, when IntelliJ IDEA runs tests for your code, it does not save or load settings for your components. You can trigger the settings saving manually if you need, but in general it's not necessary for you to do that.

Please post a separate question regarding storing multiple instances of your configuration objects.

Comment: I serialize quite a complex data (I mean not a couple of String-s but several classes with another classes inside) and I would like to test that all my data is "well-serializable". I mean that I don't miss `public` modifier or an annotation etc. I see that I can test that using serialization with XmlSerializer but I would like to have a more straight way.

Comment: Question regarding storing multiple instances I solved - I store a list of them because I understood that I don't need many files. Thank you.